# Would it be a good idea to create String resources in Java such as with Android?

Tags: java, oop

I'm currently working on a desktop Java application as well as an unrelated Android project, and I've come to realize how handy it can be to have all your String resources in one place. Would it be a good idea to create a static String constant class and reference those values throughout the application, instead of hard-coding it all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Such an approach is usually recommended. You can also use Property files as shown [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/).

Comment: Thank you, was only asking because I've never seen it done that way. Good idea using Properties too, I'll take a good look. +1 :)

Comment: @paranoid-android: They usually help when you need to pass in configuration values. Saves having to recompile each time.